# Buying a UK property but from another country

Tags: united-kingdom, norway

My sister in law is looking to buy a UK property as a holiday home, she lives in Norway, other than our normal buying costs, is there any other taxes or fees she has to pay as a non UK resident ?

Answer (score 1):

She would have to pay council tax (property tax) to the local authority.

Comment: -1: the OP is asking for fees specific to non-UK-resident house purchases, which this is not.

Comment: non residents owning property have to pay Council tax whch is part of the tax on a holiday home - there are rumors that non residents may have to pay extra council tax in the future